# How to read http status code from a Task<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>?

Tags: c#, rest

How to read http status code from a Task when calling custom api?

I use the `App.systemServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync()` to call my REST based API on my server.  My api do some calculations and returns a string value for example "15 rows updated".

```
var result = await App.systemServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync("myapi", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

To read the result i convert the result to a string. My qustion is how do i get the http status code from the `InvokeApiAsync` request? The result from the function is a `Task<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>` which has to status code member.

Documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.imobileserviceclient.invokeapiasync

Comment: Do you mean "... has *no* status code..." ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not Task.Status property?

Comment: I think so, the result, which is a JToken do not seem to have a get status code member function or any similar way to get a 200, 403 or 401response code...

Comment: @DenysProdan `Task.Status` has nothing to do with http status.

Comment: @TechLabradoodle You may need to call the api a different way - with less abstraction through that client library. Try it with `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes, but i do have the user credentials in the systemServerclient so when I call an Api that is controlled by authentication so I need that user info in my resquest

Comment: @TechLabradoodle you can investigate how to pass these credentials to your API. It could be HttpHeaders, for example

Comment: @TechLabradoodle I understand it is convenient but if it doesn't meet your requirements then you need another option. Can you intentionally craft a request that will error? Maybe the result will have error information that will work for you.

Comment: then i will have to do that, thanks, I will start with a simple httpclient